# Haskell - Lisp-like symbol functionality

Tags: haskell, lisp, symbols

I wrote a LISP function a while back that matched nested lists of symbols against other lists. It worked something like this:

```
(match '(a b c) '(1 2 3))
  => ((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))
(match '(a b (c d)) '(1 (2 3) (4 5)))
  => ((a 1) (b (2 3)) (c 4) (d 5))
```

I am now trying to achieve a similar functionality in Haskell. What I am looking for is something that allows readable symbols to be used in indexing the results. I could use integers, but the lists involved tended to get a bit unreadable like that. Is there an easy symbol like type in Haskell?

I have come across Data.Atom.Simple, I just want something that is less awkward than that.

Comment: Can you write the code using something like `ByteString` as your symbol type and then explain what you want to be different?

Comment: Why not make it polymorphic and let the user decide what a symbol looks like? Make an instance of [Align](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.6.1.0/docs/Data-Align.html) for [Tree](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.7.1/docs/Data-Tree.html), for example, seems like pretty much exactly what you want.

Comment: After hacking at it for over an hour, I discovered that `Align` isn't actually what you need :)

Comment: You cannot describe many nested lists of arbitrary depth as a list in Haskell since list in Haskell is homogenous. The corresponding data structure is a rose tree having values only on leaf nodes, i.e. `data RoseTree a = Leaf a | Forest [RoseTree a]`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much knowledge about lisp so I don't know if you are setting variables or creating an associative array.

You could do something like - to set variables:

```
Main Data.Tree> let (Node a ((Node b []):c:[])) = Node 'a' [Node 'b' [],Node 'c' []]
*Main Data.Tree> a
'a'
*Main Data.Tree> b
'b'
*Main Data.Tree> c
Node {rootLabel = 'c', subForest = []}
```

But honestly **I wouldn't recommend it** - matching on lists is very unsafe and as far as my knowledge is concerned I don't know about a "safe" pattern matching that would result in a `Maybe x`.

If you want to have an associative array, you can use a function like this

```
aux :: Ord k => Tree k -> Tree v -> Map k v
aux a b = fromList (go a b)
  where go :: Tree k -> Tree v -> [(k,v)]
        go (Node k kk) (Node v vv) = (k,v):(concat $ zipWith go kk vv)
```

**Note:** this function only works if those trees have the same structure

```
atree = Node 'a' [Node 'b' [],Node 'c' []]
btree = Node 1 [Node 2 [],Node 3 []]
ctree = Node 1 [Node 2 [],Node 3 [], Node 4 []]

GHCi> aux atree btree
 fromList [('a','1'),('b','2'),('c','3')]
GHCi> aux atree ctree
 fromList [('a','1'),('b','2'),('c','3')]
```

So you see this function cuts the `Node 4 []` off.

Comment: Note the `Tree a` and `Map k v` are from the [`containers`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers) package

Answer (score 0):

As others have already noted, Haskell is strictly typed. Therefore lists cannot hold arbitrary list structures without reflecting it in the type. Until you have clarified that, I'll go with the most simple case. Let's assume we have the following

```
a :: [String]
a = ["a", "b", "c"]
b :: [Integer]
b = [1, 2, 3]

match = zip
match a b == [("a",1),("b",2),("c",3)]
```

Depending on which type you would actually like to use, have a look at the usually provided zip function.